# HttpClient PostAsync gives me an empty result for json page

Tags: c#, json, windows-8, httpclient

I have the following setup:

**Server side**

```
<?php

$array = ...;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

**Client side**

In my iPhone app, I successfully connected to my server side and parsed the json and loaded it into a NSDictionary.

Now I would like to do the same in C# for a Windows app. I have used this test code:

```
public async void PostData(string url, string post) 
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(post));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("RESULT|" + result + "|");
}
```

I have tried

```
PostData("http://www.mysite.com", "");
```

and it returned the html of my website.

But when I access my json url by

```
PostData("http://www.mysite.com/api/", "");
```

the string result is always empty.

I have no idea what is going on here. Is some header wrong on my server side? Or why is my string result always empty? How would I debug this - please note that I am new to Windows development?

Or is there even a faster way to download and save the json into my Windows app?

Comment: What does Fiddler tell you?

Comment: What about adding the charset to the Content-Type response. PHP uses to send ISO8859-1 responses, while .NET usually expects UTF-8.

Comment: I've added charset utf-8 in the PHP script, but that does not seem to help. I don't know Fiddler, I gotta look into it...

Comment: Tested Fiddler, already found the error. Thanks Stephen and Kiewic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fiddler I found out, that there was no error, but really an empty string as return result.

An emtpy string was returned when using the Windows device because of my PHP implementation. The problem clearly was server side.